# Insert javascript variable inside href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically generate an HTML link and have that link be the `href` attribute of my anchor tag inside my AngularJS application. I have the code below:

```
const objectUrl = baseUrl + s3Bucket + '/' + objectKey;
const link = '<a href=`${objectUrl}`> MyLink</a>';
```

I thought that using JS's string templating would work but this inserts `%60$%7BobjectUrl%7D%60` at the end of URL. I've also tried

```
const link = '<a href={{objectUrl}}> MyLink</a>';
```

but that gives me the same literal string `%60$%7BobjectUrl%7D%60`. Is there any way to insert the variable so that the href link becomes `baseUrl + s3Bucket + '/' + objectKey`?

Comment: How do you insert `link` in your template? Why don't you write the acncor tag in your template and use ng-href="{{objectUrl}}" on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the template string the other way around. The `` ` `` should go on the outside of your string.

```js
const objectUrl = 'yourURL';
const link = `<a href="${objectUrl}">MyLink</a>`;

console.log(link);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
const link = '<a href="'+objectUrl+'" > MyLink</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{objectUrl}}">My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```
const link = `<a href="${objectUrl}">MyLink</a>`
```